# Does google colaboratory save code in local computer when using local runtime

Tags: linux, security, python, google, privacy

When running python code from google colab into local computer (local runtime), does the code is saved in the local computer or not ?

Comment: Please do not ask this here. This site is about managing IT in a business setting. Please [read the help page on what's on topic](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)